# SQL multiple results in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables such as these:

```
 1. reports:                   2. schedule:
     | id   | data        |        | rpt  | username |
     -------|-------------|        |------|----------|
     | 1110 | aaaaaaaaa   |        | 1110 | name3    |
     | 1120 | bbbbbbbbb   |        | 1110 | name3    |
     | 1130 | ccccccccc   |        | 1110 | name1    |
     | 1140 | ddddddddd   |        | 1130 | name1    |
     | 1150 | eeeeeeeee   |        | 1140 | name1    |
     | 1160 | fffffffff   |        | 1140 | name2    |
                                   | 1150 | name2    |
                                   | 1160 | name3    |
```

When searching for a username, I would like to check the schedule table for all the report ids where this name appears (it may appear more than once per report, I only need it once), and then get a result table with the report ids and data.

So for `name3` I should get: `1110 aaaaaaaaa | 1160 fffffffff`

And for `name1`:             `1110 aaaaaaaaa | 1130 ccccccccc | 1140 ddddddddd`

I tried to do it with this code line:

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE id=(SELECT DISTINCT rpt FROM schedule WHERE username='name3')
```

The problem is that in the case of name3 I get this error message:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.6.33]Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

What is the correct way to solve it?

Comment: As you have multiple records with `name3` in your schedule table, it will return all records with `name3` in it, and if subquery have multiple rows, then you can't compare it with `ID` and `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper comparison is either `= ANY` or `IN`.  When using a subquery, though, you do not need the `SELECT DISTINCT` inside the subquery.  So, this should be written as:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM reports r
WHERE r.id IN (SELECT s.rpt FROM s.schedule WHERE s.username = 'name3');
```

When referring to multiple tables in a query, you should always qualify column names.  This helps prevent unexpected bugs.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.. Actually in my original code I did include the table names dot column names. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT rpt FROM schedule WHERE username='name3')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it only once then add `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE id=(SELECT DISTINCT rpt FROM schedule WHERE username='name3' LIMIT 1)
```

If you need all results, change `=` to `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE id IN(SELECT DISTINCT rpt FROM schedule WHERE username='name3')
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a subsequery.  Inner join will perform better

SELECT DISTINCT r.id,r.data
FROM reports r
INNER JOIN schedule s
ON  r.id = s.rpt
AND  s.username = 'name3'

Comment: Thanks, this is also a good idea, I thought maybe with a sub query it would be easier.